# What are the pros and cons of specifying a Controller class via URL vs. having a script for each Controller?

Tags: php, security, theory

I have setup two different PHP systems this summer. Each uses two different methods:

**Method #1: One PHP File Per Task**

This method requires that a `PHP` file be created for each major task. For example, my upload script would be access via `http://www.domain.com/upload.php`. On `upload.php`, a "controller" and a "view" class are instantiated and used. For example, `upload.php` might look something like this:

```
<?php
require_once PATH_LIBRARY . 'control/Uploader.class.php';
require_once PATH_LIBRARY . 'view/UploaderPage.class.php';

$uploader = new Uploader();
$uploader->setView(new UploaderPage());
$uploader->init();
?>
```

In the above script, if I wanted to call on another script, I would simply redirect and append the neccessary URL encoded variables (`header('Location: edit_details.php?image_id=456');`).

**Method #2: A main `index.php` file that handles all requests**

This method does not require that a `PHP` file be created for each major task. Instead, each "controller" class that will be used in the system is registered on `index.php` with a unique class that I call `Router`. The router decides if the specified Controller is legal or illegal and acts accordingly (routes the browser to the correct controller). For example, a simplified version of the `index.php` script:

```
<?php
require_once 'bootstrap.inc';
require_once PATH_LIBRARY . 'router/Router.class.php';

$router = new Router();
$router->register('Uploader', PATH_LIBRARY . 'control/Uploader.class.php');
$router->register('DetailsEditor', PATH_LIBRARY . 'control/DetailsEditor.class.php');
$router->route();
?>
```

Thus, every action takes place at `index.php`. There is no need for a lot of files which don't do much else that instantiate a specific view and controller class. BUT, if you want to call script/class A from script/class B, then you need to pass the controller class's name along on the URL: `header('Location: index.php?controller=DetailsEditor&image_id=456')`.

So far, I don't really like the fact that I need to include the Controller name in the URL. I feel that it exposes too much of my underlying system to the end-user. But, I do like the fact that I can register all controller classes on one page. Mostly, I don't know if exposing the controller name is safe or not. One other annoyance is that, if I want to call on a script via POST requests, I have to include a hidden input that specifies the required controller class (e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="DetailsEditor" />`).

I hope that is enough to go on. I am just nervous that the second method is not really going to serve me well in the months ahead. I have a small window of time soon to choose one or the other.

Thank-you.

Comment: Sorry that it took me seven months to respond, but the answers provided are excellent and informative. I am finally going with Ian's solution, which is to just have a file for each PHP action. Mainly because I lack server administration experience and don't have time right now to learn how to implement url-rewriting. Also, since I locked myself into the `front controller` design seven months ago, I find that it is tedious and annoying to keep to that design, primarily because there really isn't a good reason on my part to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not so fast.** The approach with one PHP file per action can be faster and better. It depends on how you set things up.

- The web server will route the HTTP request to the correct handler based on the filename. Why reinvent that?
- Most times, all you need for a "handler" is:

  ```
  <?php include "everything.php";
  // do some work
  // Bounce the browser to a "view" url or display an error.
  ```

  which is all at least as concise.

Comment: Would you comment on the issue of dealing with URL-rewriting? @grossvogel mentions this in his answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the big thing is that URL rewriting is an administrative task -- you have to set up the web server to cooperate. Also, it can be easier to correlate maintenance requests with files than with rewritten URLs. That's why I tend toward the "many small scripts, big include area" approach.

Answer (score 4):

Handling with Router is more efficient, because You have only one place to change, if You'll be forced to change file/dir structure in a future, and if any collaborators will come, its much more easy to understand how system works if every loads is done by just one "router/algorithm"

Just my opinion

PS imagine if You'll have to change dir structure, You'll be forced to rewrite a bunch of includes, witch is time consuming, and can produce mistakes, and takes time :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use the second option you should use [URL rewriting](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html) to turn the URLs into a nice, human-readable format. That way gives you flexibility and power - definitely the way to go. This method is generally called a [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), btw.

Answer (score 3):

The front controller is nice b/c you avoid all of those simple script files, and it also gives you lots more flexibility. In this method, you don't *have* to specify the controller name in the url, as long as the Router has a way to find the correct view.

My advice would be to use the Router class to generate your links, too. That way, instead of

```
header('Location: index.php?controller=DetailsEditor&image_id=456')
```

your redirect would look like

```
$router->redirect ($router->getUrl ('editimagedetails', array(456)));
// example getUrl method signature is     
//    string getUrl (string $viewOrActionName, array $params)
```

Naturally, `getUrl` would be used to generate links and form action urls as well.

Any changes (say turning URL-rewriting on or off or renaming query string parameters) involve only the Router class because the name `DetailEditor` and the query string parameter `image_id` are implementation details unknown to the client code.